# ShareDB - Run Database queries in middleware

Tags: javascript, mongodb, middleware, collaborative, sharedb

Currently i am dealing with the following situation:

I have a ShareDB backend up and running in order to realize real time collaboration (text writing).

Every time a user connects i would like to check if the document the user intends to work on exists in the database. If it DOES NOT exist, create it first. If it DOES exist, proceed normally, this should be done in the "connect" middleware:

```
var backend = new ShareDB();

backend.use('connect', function(context, next) {
  console.log('connect')

  var connection = backend.connect();
  doc = connection.get('collection_name', 'document_id');
  doc.fetch(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (doc.type === null) {
      doc.create({content: ''});
      return;
    }
  });

  next()
})
```

But it triggers an infinite loop, because i trigger an connect action inside the connect middleware.

So i have no idea how i to access the database in the middleware... any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `doc.fetch` callback only handles scenarios if there is an error or no document exists. See `callback` here: https://github.com/share/sharedb/blob/master/examples/textarea/server.js#L11-L22

Comment: Additionally, you may not want to call `next()` at the end as you currently are. This will be called regardless of the outcome of fetch. Consider referencing `next` in your fetch when the fetch has settled to an error or success.

Comment: Hey @GenericUser , the example you referenced handles the document creation at server start. What i want to do is: Run createDoc() every time the user connects to sharedb (in the middleware), any ideas?